# Twilio concurrent api call limit

Tags: twilio-api

Can someone give more details on the "100 concurrent API calls limitation" for twilio?

We need to send 1000 clients from 15 groups an SMS within one minute. To do that we bought 40 twilio numbers and created our own "sticky sender".

There is a 3 second delay between each SMS sending instead of the expected 1 per second.

How fast can I get these messages sent without getting any delayed or lost messages.

buying more numbers will not help because of the  "100 concurrent api calls limitation" but i dont see anywhere in the twilio docs more info on exactly how that works.

Comment: Wondering the same thing.. Twilio is so vague -_-

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since you asked this question, but in case somebody else comes across this post, I wanted to share: Twilio now has [documentation for understanding Message Per Second (MPS) throughput](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues#h_01F026611PX5077RHR86SHGBYQ) (relevant for your use case), as well as Messaging Services with features like [Sticky Sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#sticky-sender). Finally, you may want to consider your Phone Number strategy - if you need higher throughput, [Application-to-person 10-digit Long Codes (A2P 10DLCs)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260803225669-Message-throughput-MPS-and-Trust-Scores-for-A2P-10DLC-in-the-US), High Throughput Toll Free numbers, or Short Codes may all be options.